# mapkit overlay is readonly, how to remove them or refresh the entire mapview?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

The solution online to remove overlays and refresh mapview does absolutely nothing. I am sure I have all the delegates set correctly and everything hooked up. Looking for creative ways to solve this problem. What I intend to do is to show "directions" (the polyline) to new destination coordinates only, but not the old destination. But once they are added, they cannot be removed it seems...

```
 [mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]];
```

and

```
 [mapView setNeedsDisplay];
```

both does nothing!

Comment: Try logging [mapView overlays] just before and after your call to removeOverlays:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is nothing else wrong? The method to remove an overlay works fine, I use it all the time like this:

```
if (_directionsOverlay != nil) {
    [self.mapView removeOverlay:_directionsOverlay];
    _directionsOverlay = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the call runs on the UI thread.